# Trouble with a postback in MVC from a group of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On a User Create view I have the following to show a list of Region checkboxes the user could be associated with. (click all that apply kind of thing)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
            Select User Region(s)
        </label>
        <span class=" col-md-10">
            @foreach (var item in Model.RegionsList)
            {
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRegions" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />
                    @Html.Label(item.Text, new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
            }
        </span>
    </div>
```

It is displayed just fine. But after I check a box or two, and then click the 'Create' button, the browser replies with this:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:  (line 38)

Line 36:         </label>
Line 37:         <span class=" col-md-10">
Line 38:             @foreach (var item in Model.RegionsList)
Line 39:             {
Line 40:                 <div>
```

Here is how I set up that view:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var viewModel = new RegisterUserViewModel();
            viewModel.SelectedRole = "User";
            viewModel.RolesList = context.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Selected = false,
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.Name
            });
            viewModel.RegionsList = context.Regions.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                Selected = false
            });

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Ant this is the signature of the postback handler.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Email,Id,SelectedRole")] RegisterUserViewModel registerUser, params string[] selectedRegions)
        {
```

I don't get it, the page just rendered fine passing through that code. Why does it fail on the postback? and for that matter, why is it even going thru the cshtml again?

Comment: Looks like `Model` is null on your postback, step though the `Create` method and see what gets passed into the `View`, without seeing you postback method its hard to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown the full post method code but I assume your returning the view which is when the error occurs.  Since your not posting back any properties of `RegionsList` the value of `registerUser.RegionsList` will be null so when you return the view and again use `@foreach (var item in Model.RegionsList) {..` an exception will be thrown.  You need to reassign the value of `RegionsList` before returning the view.

Note use of `SelectListItem` is not really appropriate here and you should consider using a view model to represent Roles and Regions so selected values are retaining when returning the view

Comment: Why does it return to that code? After I click the button shouldn't it run the [HttpPost] method and then go to an index page or a details page? Why would it resend the create page?

Comment: I cant tell because you haven't posted all of your code for the POST method